# Windows 10 pop3 and imap is disabled, is there a way to enable it

Tags: windows-10, email, microsoft-outlook, office365

Is there a way to enable pop3 and IMAP.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the graying options can be modified through the registry. Please follow the following steps to troubleshooting:

1.Win+R>type ***regedit*** in the Open box, and then select OK;

2.Locate and then select the registry subkey:
***Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\xx.0\Outlook\Options***;
(Note: The xx.0 placeholder represents your version of Office (16.0 = Office 2016, Office 365 and Office 2019, 15.0 = Office 2013));

3.Check if there are the following three values. If so, please delete them.
[image]

4.Then restart Outlook and configure your account, the graying options will be available.

(It should be noted that if you modify the registry by mistake, serious problems may occur. Please [back up the registry](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/how-to-back-up-and-restore-the-registry-in-windows-855140ad-e318-2a13-2829-d428a2ab0692) before operation.)

Hope the above help！

Comment: I have it.. but with `0` and not `1`. and those options are still disabled. I deleted them and still options are greyed out.

Comment: Do you belong to an organization? If so, contact your administrator to check if some group policy settings disable this option.